# Unable to change text on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a codepen at http://codepen.io/templenaylor/pen/ggoMPZ?editors=0011

I am currently displaying a temperature that references a var:

```
<ul>
  <li id="fTemp"></li>
</ul>
```

When trying to change it by clicking it, it will not work. This is the function I am using to do that:

```
  $("#fTemp").click(function(){
    if(tempSwap===false){
      $("#fTemp").html(fTemp + " &#8457;");
      tempSwap=true;
    } else{
      $("fTemp").html(cTemp + " &#8451;");
      tempSwap=false;
    }
  });
```

Is there something I am not seeing within my function that is incorrect?

Comment: `$("fTemp")` should be `$("#fTemp")`

Comment: Very good catch @MichaelCoker. One thing i recommend is that you cache the button in a variable so you don't have to write it many times and misspell it again. `var tempText = $("#fTemp");` now use `tempTxt`

Comment: Your codepen doesn't work since the AJAX call isn't working, but I made this. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/EZoJgp You just need to define tempSwap as true or false before your conditional and change the `$('#fTemp')` selector I commented with previously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @MichaelCoker, you are missing the `#` in your else branch.

In addition to fixing that, I would save the element to a variable to help prevent errors in the future.

```
var ftemp_li = $("#fTemp");

ftemp_li.click(function(){
  if(tempSwap == false){
    ftemp_li.html(fTemp + " &#8457;");
    tempSwap = true;
  } else {
    ftemp_li.html(cTemp + " &#8451;");
    tempSwap = false;
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPyNPO?editors=0011

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Helped with something blatant my eyes weren't seeing and gave me a prevention to a possible bug later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not referencing the correct selector in your `else` block

```
} else{
      $("fTemp").html(
```

is supposed to be

```
} else{
      $("#fTemp").html(
```

Also you seem to binding the click event **every single time your ajax is successful**.

Move it out of the callback and bind your click event in DOM ready handler.